# Google Earth produces error ERR_MAX_EARTH_PROCESSES

Tags: google-earth-plugin

As the title suggests, I'm running into the cryptic error,**ERR_MAX_EARTH_PROCESSES**, while trying to add points to a google earth instance. Normally, I'd trawl through google's forums, but according to a web search, there is only 4 pages in the entire internet that mentions this error and none of them seem relevant.

Any ideas? I don't have direct access to the production environment, but I assume the client has thousands or even tens of thousands of points he is trying to display at once, but I'm not sure. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track, as no one seems to know this error exists.

Comment: How are the points being added - in a loop via the api, via kml, networkinks, etc? Also are you using the execute batch function from the google.earth namespace in your code?

Comment: It's via a loop calling the API. Though see my answer below. I was on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was on the wrong track. The ERR_MAX_EARTH_PROCESSES actually refers to how many instances of the Google Earth plugin are being displayed.

The client reporting this error had multiple tabs open and closing all except one would fix the problem.

This may also be caused by an instance of Google Earth not exiting cleanly, as when a page is unresponsive.